# Delete from CoreData not working on app retstart

Tags: swift, core-data, nsmanagedobject, completion

I have a function that deletes an `NSManagedObject` from CoreData (`Test` is a subclass of `NSManagedObject`:

```
public func delete(_ test: Test, completion: @escaping (Bool) -> Void) {
    guard let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate else { return completion(false) }

    let managedContext = appDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext

    do {
        managedContext.delete(test)
        completion(true)
    } catch let error as NSError {
        print("Could not delete. \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
        completion(false)
    }
}
```

Right now, it appears that the object is being deleted from CoreData in the moment, but if I rerun my app, the object that I just deleted appears again. What am I doing wrong when trying to delete this object?

Comment: Does my answer solve your problem?

Answer (score 0):

You have to save the context to make changes persist, including deletions.

```
do {
    try managedContext.save()
} catch let error as NSError {
    print("Unresolved error \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
}
```